# What is the KOMA input to make the "Contents" in Table of Contents be the scrbook default font?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, koma-script, scrbook

I am trying to change the font in my scrbook document back to the scrbook default. All of the chapters, sections, and parts are in a different font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[sf]{titlesec}


\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.65} \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}} \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\flushleft \fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\ \Huge\bfseries}[]

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.65} \newcommand{\hspace{0pt}} \titleformat{\part}[hang]{\flushleft \fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\ \Huge\bfseries}[]

\title{Math Handouts}

\author{XYZ}

\date{2021}

\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage

\begin{document} \maketitle

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface} something

\chapter{Introduction} somebody

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{Algebra}

\chapter{Chapter name}


\part{Number Theory}

\chapter{Chapter name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not seeing it. Never mind the default, what is the result you're looking for? (Non-) Serif? Bold? Something with the font size? Also, please remove as much superfluous code from your example as you can, and make sure we can actually compile it: I for one have no idea what `evan.sty`(?) is, and it's not an CTAN.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary code from the file so you can compile. That unfortunately doesnt fix the problem as that is a question I wrote about the same issue. Thank you though.

Comment: That comment was inserted automatically, when I pointed out the duplicate question to the system. That said, your code still doesn't compile on my TexLive 2021 setup: `LaTeX Error: Command \hsp already defined.`

Comment: It should compile now, I defined hsp twice because I was defining the numbering for two separate parts.

Comment: you should edit the existing question not make two posts asking the same thing,